# How do i bind arrow keys and mousehweel

Tags: jquery, bind, mousewheel

I want arrow keys and mousewheel to do the same thing,

I m using a mousewheel plugin:

```
$(function() {
   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

and i have my code to bind key

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
     alert( "left pressed" );
     return false;
  }
});
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to combine both of them, please help?

Comment: I want mousewheel and left key to scroll left